# Homepage | Index of

Tags: craft3

I want to create a staging site, on our production site and I dont know why on the homepage we've got an index of all the folders and if we click on web's folder, we can view the site.

Someone had an idea to solde this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server doesn't point to your `web` directory. In order to see your homepage directly you need to change the path your URL points to

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but how can I change the path? I try with the .env without success...

Comment: That's a setting in your web server and can't be done via Craft nor your PHP files. The only thing you could do is to move your index PHP from your web directory but I would really highly suggest not to do that cause it's a security lack (cause users will be able to access your server and your config files)